# Is there a way to install a previous version of Chocolatey?

Tags: chocolatey

The latest version of chocolatey (9.9.x) has broken all of my private packages, and they cannot be rebuilt at this time.  Is there way to install version 9.8.x of chocolatey itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just got a response from Rob Reynolds on this.  To install the old POSH version:

> use https://chocolatey.org/install-lastposhclient.ps1 instead of
>   https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1.

So, this means the install line would look like this:

```
(iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install-lastposhclient.ps1')))>$null 2>&1
```

I just tested this, and it's working.